# Search points located within given distance from a path in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Below is the biz document, in it address.location is where I saved the coordinates.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59944c26085e1140d4575393"),
    "category" : "place",
    "address" : {
        "streetAddress" : "19210 Clay Road",
        "city" : "Katy",
        "zipcode" : "77449",
        "state" : "Texas",
        "country" : "United States",
        "countryCode" : "US",
        "locality" : "Katy, TX",
        "location" : {
            "type" : "Point",
            "coordinates" : [ 
                -95.7043599, 
                29.832139
            ]
        },
        "fomattedAddress" : "19210 Clay Rd, Katy, TX 77449"
    }
}
```

With the below logic I calculated the polygon

```
Coordinate[] coordinates = new Coordinate[] {new Coordinate(-84.529793, 33.961886), new Coordinate( -84.521698, 33.952987),
                new Coordinate(-84.517242, 33.944534), new Coordinate(-84.513290, 33.937264), new Coordinate( -84.498865, 33.915202), new Coordinate(-84.529793, 33.961886)};
GeometryFactory geometryFactory = new GeometryFactory();
LinearRing linear = new GeometryFactory().createLinearRing(coordinates);
Polygon polygon = new Polygon(linear, null, geometryFactory);
Coordinate[] polyCoordinates = polygon.getCoordinates();
```

With the below mongo query I am trying to get the businesses inside the polygon, but I get no results, am i doing somthing wrong please guide me

```
db.business.find(
   {
     "address.location.coordinates": {
       $geoIntersects: {
          $geometry: {
             type: "Polygon" ,
             coordinates: [
               [ [ -84.529793, 33.961886 ], [ -84.521698, 33.952987 ], [ -84.517242, 33.944534 ], [-84.51329, 33.937264]  , [ -84.498865, 33.915202 ], [-84.529793, 33.961886] ]
             ]
          }
       }
     }
   }
)
```

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/geoIntersects/#op._S_geoIntersects

Comment: but I am not able to give radius with this approach, if possible could you help me with a working query, in which i can pass array of coordinates, radius and I get the search result

Comment: you need to calculate coordinates of the poly around your path so that width of the poly = 2 x radius. There's nothing built in, you need to do the math on application level.

Comment: Please see my below approach, I am still struggling how to get coordinates of the polygon, plz help

Comment: I'd recommend to add your "answer" to the question itself. Such posts violate rules of Stackoverflow. Answers suppose to give an answer, and all information that exposes your attempts to solve the problem should be included in the question itself.

Comment: I have updated my question, do you see anything wrong in that?

Comment: Your poly is just your route with joined ends. You didn't calculate coordinates of the poly **around** the route. I have added an answer with a bit of explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find all points within certain distance along the route you need to build a poly **around** the route.

On the image below I assumed the whole route (green) is a straight line for brevity and clarity. Your query is an `$or` of 3 shapes - blue start and end point circles with radius R, and a red poly that joins both:

[image]

Following javascript code https://jsfiddle.net/961kcxr3/ calculates coordinates for a segment using basic flat geometry. This is what you need to do on application level using your language of choice:

```
const routeCoords [ [ -84.529793, 33.961886 ], [ -84.521698, 33.952987 ], [ -84.517242, 33.944534 ], [-84.51329, 33.937264]  , [ -84.498865, 33.915202 ] ] ];

const R = 1000; // 1 km - radius to search within, adjust to your needs
const M = 1/98000; // radius to radians multiplier

const A = routeCoords[0];
const B = routeCoords[4];
const a = Math.atan2(B[0] - A[0], B[1] - A[1]) + Math.PI / 2;

var polyCoords = [ 
    [
        A[0] - Math.sin(a) * R * M,
        A[1] - Math.cos(a) * R * M
    ], [
        B[0] - Math.sin(a) * R * M,
        B[1] - Math.cos(a) * R * M
    ], [
        B[0] + Math.sin(a) * R * M,
        B[1] + Math.cos(a) * R * M
    ], [
        A[0] + Math.sin(a) * R * M,
        A[1] + Math.cos(a) * R * M
    ]
];
```

Which gives you coordinates of the poly:

```
[
    [-84.516182, 33.970903],
    [-84.485254, 33.924219],
    [-84.512476, 33.906185],
    [-84.543404, 33.952869]
]
```

And the resulting query:

```
db.business.find(
   { $or: [
       { "address.location.coordinates": {
           $geoWithin: {
              $geometry: {
                 type: "Polygon" ,
                 coordinates: [ [
                     [-84.516182, 33.970903],
                     [-84.485254, 33.924219],
                     [-84.512476, 33.906185],
                     [-84.543404, 33.952869],
                     [-84.516182, 33.970903]  // the first point to close the poly
                 ] ]
              }
           },
       } },
       { "address.location.coordinates": {
           $geoWithin: {
               $centerSphere: [ [ -84.529793, 33.961886 ], 1 / 6378.1 ] 
           }, // 1 km radius, adjust to your needs
       } },
       { "address.location.coordinates": {
           $geoWithin: {
               $centerSphere: [ [ -84.498865, 33.915202 ], 1 / 6378.1 ] 
           }, // 1 km radius, adjust to your needs
       } }
   ] }

)
```

The real-life code should calculate polygons and circles for each segment. It can result with quite large query, so be reasonable balancing between accuracy and speed.

Some cases for optimisation:

- if length of a segment is significantly less than the radius `R` you can skip the poly and use 2 or 1 circle for the segment.
- if angle `a` is the same for 2 consecutive segments, you can join the ends and treat them as a single segment the same way I joined 4 segments in the example above

Comment: I really appreciate your detailed response, it really helped but I am getting "Loop is not valid" exception in java , Please check the below doc link to see the coordinates of the route I am trying, 
I also mentioned polygon coordinates which is getting generated with your logic. I am badly stuck with this dont know what to do. Plz help me.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1JFsdJ9zaM2zNu_UxWfu416D5uBgHlktB

Comment: @Sam, sorry you have some errors from your code, but it is really a java question. The mongodb query in the question has invalid polygon - you just linked ends of your path instead of building a poly *around* the path. My answer address only this problem. The example code is a simplified calculation to give you a visual explanation of how to build a query combining `$geoWithin` polygons and spheres.

Comment: I have to do some math to make correct polygon and its working fine. Your logic is helped a lot. Thank you so much